# Tomcat index page not showing on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat7

Tomcat's (7.0.12) index page isn't showing up on Chrome when typing localhost:8080(it just says: "It works!"), if I remember it right, this is the Axis2 test page. It's showing up normal on Firefox though. I like Chrome!!
Also, I managed to get into it by typing http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (!). What's going on?

Comment: And you've tried, http://localhost:8080/ ?

Comment: What is the url you are entering?

Comment: how did you configure axis2 on Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

I easily resolved this problem by going to:

**Windows->show servers**

Then one window will open in down of eclipse go to Servers tab there you will see Tomcat 6.0 or 7.0 at localhost(Stopped,Unsynchronized)

**Double click this one and window will open on top screen**

Two tabs will be there *Overview* and *Modules*

**Click modules and remove modules deployed there**

Then **close it**, it will ask you to save yes or no. **Click yes**.

**Double click again**

This time stay at Overview and

**Select Use tomcat installation take control of tomcat installation.**

Close again

**Select yes to save**

Run the server go to chrome or mozilla type URL of home page to see home page.